# run batch file with /y using createprocess vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, createprocess

my batch file asking for input y/n. i run that batch file using CreateProcess() method. If i run my batch file with /y as commnad line, it not ask for input. e.g

```
run.bat /y
```

i want to run my batch file using CreateProcess() with command line /y,as above e.g, i don't know how to do this using CreateProcess() an i don't want to modify my batch file.

`::CreateProcess(L"run.bat",NULL,NULL,NULL,TRUE,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL,NULL,&startInfo,&procInfo )` 
, i also try this

`::CreateProcess(L"run.bat",L"/y",NULL,NULL,TRUE,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL,NULL,&startInfo,&procInfo )`

but,it not works. If anyone know how to do this,plz let me know.

::CreateProcess(L"run.bat",L"/y",NULL,NULL,TRUE,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL,NULL,&startInfo,&procInfo ) this works fine. it's my mistake i change in if part and my flow goes in else part. and i always change in my if part. thanks for quick reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
::CreateProcess(L"cmd.exe", L"/c run.bat /y", NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
     NULL, NULL, &startInfo, &procInfo )
```

As it [says on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> To run a batch file, you must start the command interpreter; set *lpApplicationName* to cmd.exe and set *lpCommandLine* to the following arguments: /c plus the name of the batch file.

Comment: I try this,but it's not work, I also try this `if(::CreateProcess(L"G:\\run.bat",L"\/y",NULL,NULL,TRUE,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL,NULL,&startInfo,&procInfo ) > 0)`

Comment: `CreateProcess("cmd.exe", "/c run.bat /y", ...` does not use PATH to search for `cmd.exe` so, if none is present in current directory (which is extremely likely), it fails. `CreateProcess(NULL, "cmd.exe /c run.bat /y", ...`, on the other hand, DOES search the PATH.