# Visual Studio 2010 CreateProcess() for batch script

Tags: winapi, batch-file, createprocess

I am trying to run a batch script within visual studio 2010.  I am following the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996948/run-batch-file-with-y-using-createprocess-vs2010) as well as the [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I have the `running.bat` file I created in both the Release and Debug folders when my `.exe` is created (both methods of compiling fail during runtime). However my program crashes with error code `2` every time:

main.c - a command line application

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

        if( !CreateProcess(NULL,   
        L"cmd.exe /c running.bat",        
        NULL,         
        NULL,         
        TRUE,        
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,            
        NULL,           
        NULL,           
        &si,            
        &pi )           
        ) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d)\n", GetLastError() );
        return FALSE;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STARTUPINFO is an **In** parameter for the CreateProcess function, but in your code is passing in junk.

```
STARTUPINFO si = {0};
si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
etc...
```

From the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx):

> **Important**  The caller is responsible for ensuring that the standard handle fields in STARTUPINFO contain valid handle values. These fields are copied unchanged to the child process without validation, even when the dwFlags member specifies STARTF_USESTDHANDLES. Incorrect values can cause the child process to misbehave or crash.

**As for the Exit Code 2,** Add the full path of the batch file to the command.  You can retrieve your application's current directory using [args](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx) or [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx).